# React map - How to properly handle objects when they have different properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have objects with properties the problem is that I have one property called `QuestionTitle` which is different from the rest of the objects:

```
function Questions() {
    const [task,] = useState([
        {QuestionTitle: 'QuestionTitle'},
        {value: 'best', question: 'Question 1'},
        {value: 'worst', question: 'Question 2'},
    ]);

    return (
        <Box display={"grid"} marginTop={1}>
            {
                task.map((i, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                {
                                    <h3>{i.QuestionTitle}</h3>
                                }
                                <FormControlLabel value={i.value} key={index}
                                                  control={<Radio className={"RadioButton"} size="small"/>} label={i.question}/>
                            </>
                        );
                    }
                )
            }
        </Box>
    );
}
```

In this example, I get the third empty radio button, I remember that in such cases I used "&&" to avoid all this, but I don't remember exactly how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly recommend putting the title in a different state so you don't have to worry about conflicting state shapes:

```
function Questions() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('QuestionTitle');
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
        { value: 'best', question: 'Question 1' },
        { value: 'worst', question: 'Question 2' },
    ]);

    return (
        <Box display={"grid"} marginTop={1}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            {

                questions.map((q, index) => (
                    <FormControlLabel
                        value={q.value}
                        key={index}
                        control={<Radio className={"RadioButton"} size="small" />} label={q.question}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </Box>
    );
}
```

As a side note, if the title and questions never change at all, they should probably not be stateful with `useState`, but plain `const`s, either inside or outside the component (or passed down as a prop).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
task.map((i, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                {
                                    <h3>{i?.QuestionTitle}</h3>
                                }
                                !i?.questionTitle && <FormControlLabel value={i.value} key={index}
                                                  control={<Radio className={"RadioButton"} size="small"/>} label={i.question}/>
                            </>
                        );
                    }
                )
```

Recommend that you look up optional chaining as well.